# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many only works one way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, orm

I am trying to create a many to many relationship between my `groups` table and my `keywords` table.

When I am in my controller I cant do `Keyword.groups` or `Group.keywords` as I get a no method error. I have checked `Group.methods` and  I only have these related methods

```
  "before_add_for_groups_keywords",
  "before_add_for_groups_keywords?",
  "before_add_for_groups_keywords=",
  "after_add_for_groups_keywords",
  "after_add_for_groups_keywords?",
  "after_add_for_groups_keywords=",
  "before_remove_for_groups_keywords",
  "before_remove_for_groups_keywords?",
  "before_remove_for_groups_keywords=",
  "after_remove_for_groups_keywords",
  "after_remove_for_groups_keywords?",
  "after_remove_for_groups_keywords=",
  "before_add_for_keywords",
  "before_add_for_keywords?",
  "before_add_for_keywords=",
  "after_add_for_keywords",
  "after_add_for_keywords?",
  "after_add_for_keywords=",
  "before_remove_for_keywords",
  "before_remove_for_keywords?",
  "before_remove_for_keywords=",
  "after_remove_for_keywords",
  "after_remove_for_keywords?",
  "after_remove_for_keywords=",
```

Where as `Keyword.methods` gives me these

```
  "before_add_for_keywords_groups",
  "before_add_for_keywords_groups?",
  "before_add_for_keywords_groups=",
  "after_add_for_keywords_groups",
  "after_add_for_keywords_groups?",
  "after_add_for_keywords_groups=",
  "before_remove_for_keywords_groups",
  "before_remove_for_keywords_groups?",
  "before_remove_for_keywords_groups=",
  "after_remove_for_keywords_groups",
  "after_remove_for_keywords_groups?",
  "after_remove_for_keywords_groups=",
  "before_add_for_groups",
  "before_add_for_groups?",
  "before_add_for_groups=",
  "after_add_for_groups",
  "after_add_for_groups?",
  "after_add_for_groups=",
  "before_remove_for_groups",
  "before_remove_for_groups?",
  "before_remove_for_groups=",
  "after_remove_for_groups",
  "after_remove_for_groups?",
  "after_remove_for_groups=",
```

My models

`has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords`

`has_and_belongs_to_many :groups`

My db schema is the following

```
  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "member_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false

  end

  add_index "groups", ["member_id"], name: "index_groups_on_member_id", using: :btree

  create_table "groups_keywords", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.integer "keyword_id"
  end

  add_index "groups_keywords", ["group_id", "keyword_id"], name: "index_groups_keywords_on_group_id_and_keyword_id", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "keywords", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "keyword"
    t.string   "keyword_hash"
    t.datetime "checked_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Associations are defined for **instances**.

`Keyword.groups` indeed does not exist (as a **class method**).

However, `Keyword#groups`, as in `Keyword.first.groups`, does work. The reason for that is that `Keyword.first` returns an instance of `Keyword` class, which `Keyword` class itself is not.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `Keyword.group(1)`, it doesn't do what you think it is doing. It just finds all the keywords and groups them by 1.

```
SELECT * "keywords".* FROM "keywords" GROUP BY 1
```

Indeed, you can't actually call *these kind of method* on Class level, associations are accessed through instance level. And as you have defined them `has_and_belongs_to_many`, you will have to be plural about them, not single.

```
keyword = Keyword.first
keyword.groups # Not 'group', and on instance level
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to implement a many to many relationship is with the has_many :through idiom:

```
class Keyword
  has_many :keyword_groups
  has_many :groups, :through => :keyword_groups

class Group
  has_many :keyword_groups
  has_many :keywords, :through => :keyword_groups

class KeywordGroup
  belongs_to :keyword
  belongs_to :group
```

This will give you flexibility in the future if you need to extend your join model.

Comment: When rails is giving us magic, why we are writing it ourselves?

Comment: @ArslanAli there is magic, then there is control. Perfection is somewhere in between.